# Comparing macro arguments

Tags: macros

I'm trying to compare `a` and `b` from `\f{a}` and `\g{b}`. It could be done by redefining `\f` and `\g` so that they expand to their argument, then comparing the arguments and finally resetting `\f` and `\g`'s values. But that seems really ugly. Is there a better way to do that? Something like `\skip\f{x}` → `{x}`?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

---

I apparently failed at minimizing my problem so here is the whole thing:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \eatstart { m m } { \eat_loop:NN #1 #2 }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \eatstop { m } {}
\cs_new:Npn \eat_loop:NN #1 #2
{
  \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF { #2 } { \eatstop }
  {
    #2
  }
  {
    \eat_loop_not_stop:NN { #1 } { #2 }
  }
}
\cs_new:Npn \eat_loop_not_stop:NN #1 #2
{
  \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF { #2 } { #1 }
  {
    \eat_loop:NN { #1 }
  }
  {
    \token_if_expandable:NTF { #2 }
    {
      \expandafter\eat_loop:NN\expandafter#1#2
    }
    {
      #2
    }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\newcommand{\plop}{o}
\newcommand{\plip}{i}
[] = [\eatstart{\plop}\plop\eatstop{\plip}\plop\eatstop{\plop}]
\end{document}
```

The idea is that after a `\starteat\thing`, all the `\thing`s are removed until a `\eatstop\thing` or a character is reached. My problem is that at the moment it stops at any `\eatstop` and I don't know how to make it stop only after a `\eatstop\thing`.

Comment: Sorry, but this is very unclear.

Comment: If you just want to gobble the macro and leave its argument, then you can use `\newcommand{\gobble}[1]{}`.

Comment: It's still unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like the following (plain TeX syntax, which also works in LaTeX, because I do not know, what you are using):

```
\def\comparearguments#1#2#3#4{%
  \def\argI{#2}%
  \def\argII{#4}%
  \ifx\argI\argII
    \immediate\write16{* Arguments are equal.}%
  \else
    \immediate\write16{* Arguments are not equal.}%
  \fi
}

\comparearguments\f{a}\g{b}
\comparearguments\f{abc}\g{abc}
\comparearguments\f{a}\f{b}
```

Result:

```
* Arguments are not equal.
* Arguments are equal.
* Arguments are not equal.
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I hadn't stated my problem clearly. I updated the question.